How to group rows and sum costs where revenue is zero
Im trying to group all columns (except date column) I have and keep the rows where Revenue dosent equel to zero and sum all Cost columns to.
For example, the first three rows will be summed with the fourth row since their Revenue is zero. The three rows will then be dropped, and the summed Cost values will grouped be in the fourth row.
Original data shape



date
dim_channel_group
dim_channel
dim_hotel_name
dim_market
Cost
Revenue




10/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
28.5
0


11/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
108
0


12/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
126.7
0


13/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
156.1
8195.8


14/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
120.9
0


15/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
115.4
0


16/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
114.6
2352.4


10/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
34.1
0


11/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
42.7
0


12/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
93.6
0


13/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
29.3
3500


14/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
44.8
0


15/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
88.6
0


16/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
35.5
0


17/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
81.9
7500



Desired data shape



date
dim_channel_group
dim_channel
dim_hotel_name
dim_market
Cost
Revenue




13/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
419.3
8195.8


16/10/2023
Social
Snapchat
Hotel A
KSA
350.9
2352.4


13/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
199.7
3500


17/01/2023
Search
Google
Hotel B
Australia
250.8
7500




So what exactly is your question..?

Compute a grouper with a df.loc[::-1, 'Revenue'].ne(0).cumsum() (reverse boolean cumsum) and perform a custom aggregation:
g = df.loc[::-1, 'Revenue'].ne(0).cumsum()

out = (df.groupby(g, sort=False)
         .agg({'date': 'last', 'dim_channel_group': 'last', 'dim_channel': 'last',
               'dim_hotel_name': 'last', 'dim_market': 'last', 
               'Cost': 'sum', 'Revenue': 'sum'})
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

Variant to define the aggregations more easily:
g = df.loc[::-1, 'Revenue'].ne(0).cumsum()

# pick last row by default
agg_f = dict.fromkeys(df, 'last')
# for Cost/Revenue, take the sum
agg_f['Cost'] = 'sum'
agg_f['Revenue'] = 'sum'

out = (df.groupby(g, sort=False)
         .agg(agg_f)
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

Output:
         date dim_channel_group dim_channel dim_hotel_name dim_market   Cost  Revenue
0  13/10/2023            Social    Snapchat        Hotel A        KSA  419.3   8195.8
1  16/10/2023            Social    Snapchat        Hotel A        KSA  350.9   2352.4
2  13/01/2023            Search      Google        Hotel B  Australia  199.7   3500.0
3  17/01/2023            Search      Google        Hotel B  Australia  250.8   7500.0


If the sort state is like the example, the following code is probably the easiest to use
cond =  df['Revenue'].ne(0)
grp = cond.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
out = df[cond].assign(Cost=df.groupby(grp)['Cost'].sum().values)

out

If they are not sorted by group, use the code below
cols = ['dim_channel_group', 'dim_channel', 'dim_hotel_name', 'dim_market']
grp1 = [df[col] for col in cols]
grp2 = (df['Revenue'].ne(0).groupby(grp1).shift(fill_value=False)
                     .groupby(grp1).cumsum())
out = (df.groupby(grp1 + [grp2], sort=False)
         .agg({'date': 'last', 'Cost':'sum', 'Revenue': 'last'})
         .droplevel(-1).reset_index()[df.columns]
)

same result
